# Stop Woocommerce redirect if apply discount button on checkout clicked with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

To explain the scenario, When I manually/in person click "apply discount" button on the checkout page it applies the discount and stays on the checkout page. But if I click "apply discount" button with jquery on the checkout page ,it applies the discount **but it redirects me to the cart page if clicked with jquery**. How can I click the button on checkout page with jquery and not get redirected to another page?

jquery I am using to click button :

```
if (location.search === '?477236546456456465465') { 
    jQuery(".wc_points_rewards_apply_discount").click()
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are missing a ; (semicolon) after the click() method. This may throw an error. I am not entirely sure if you are looking for something to simulate a click (a user does not actually click on the button) or use an event listener to wait for a click on the button, I'll go with the first from how your code looks.

As far as I know, jQuery's .click() method is a shortcut for the method .on('click', handler) - which is essentially an event listener that is waiting for a physical click on an element.

According to jQuery's .click() documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/), "The click event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over the element, and the mouse button is pressed and released."

With all of that being said, here is some code that may work using a jQuery method preventDefault(). This will prevent the default action of the clicking the element from occurring. However, the click() method will not simulate a click. Good Luck!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if (location.search === '?477236546456456465465') { 
jQuery(".wc_points_rewards_apply_discount").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 //do some cool stuff
 });
}
});
```

Edit: My original answer will wait until all DOM content has loaded. However, 
 to wait until all Window content has loaded (included images, etc.), you can try putting your code in the following:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
      //do stuff after the window has fully loaded
 });
```

In order to wait until all ajax processes have stopped, you can try adding code to the following:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function() {
   /*do stuff after all ajax has stopped. This will be called even if 
   an ajax event occurs after the page loaded */
});
```

Comment: Hi, After playing around with it I think I need an event listener to wait and need to check if any other AJAX events are currently in progress and that the button is ready. do you know what the code will be to wait for everything to load on checkout first then click? and thanks

Comment: Hello. Please adjust your question to reflect the question in your comment. I'll add some code to my answer.